# Scripting with the shell - asterisk

Tags: shell, ubuntu, asterisk

I want to write a shell script that can reload asterisk every 3 minutes. How to do this and what reload should I use? reload / reload sip or logger rotate? I am adding sip clients in sip.conf and I am also changing the extensions.conf. I would like to specify that I don't want to interrupt the calls (if there are between other sip clients) while I am reloading asterisk.

I am working in Ubuntu server.

Comment: Batch files => Windows. Shell scripts => Linux & Unix-type OSes. C++: completely unrelated.

Comment: thx very much Mat. Could you help me with a response to my question?

Comment: Not really. There's too much stuff in there, some about Asterisk, some about scripting, and you don't show much of your research effort at solving this yourself. You should keep your questions on a single topic, and be sure to show that you've already tried things, and explain what exactly is giving you trouble. (Reloading a service every three minutes sounds really strange anyway, but I don't know Asterisk at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# /usr/sbin/asterisk -h
```

Asterisk help gives:

```
-x "<CLI command>"
```

> Execute an arbitrary CLI command. Using this command in combination
>   with -r allows you to execute a CLI command without having to connect
>   to the CLI and type it manually. An example would be to send a
>   restart, which you would do by typing asterisk -rx "reload" from the
>   command line.

You probably want to use `asterisk -rx "reload when convenient"` to reload the configuration when there isn't any call volume.

Comment: i want to use reload sip and reload dialplan. I know that when using reload there is no interrupt is a call is made.

Comment: i thought about using a folder watcher and create a batch file to reload asterisk when is needed.

Comment: you mean that is there is a call on the line it will be cut off by reload-xr "reload sip" for example?

Comment: Read the docs for that. In the Asterisk commandline you can use `core show help [anything]`. voip-info.org sais "will not abort active calls"